# Analog story from past decade about an interstellar expedition which finds a planet whose inhabitants teleport members of the crew off the ship

Tags: story-identification

It was about an interstellar expedition which finds a (Europa-like?) planet whose inhabitants teleport members of the crew off the ship, killing them, then bring them back as sort of zombie servants. Eventually, the protagonist lies to the aliens about what star system she comes from, and sets off on a course for that star, so that the aliens will not find Earth.